# Comparing the properties in Firebase Auth and Firebase Object

Tags: android, visual-studio, firebase, xamarin

[firbase object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HRk5.png)

[firebase auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGsQB.png)

```
var users = await firebase
                .Child("parent")
                .OnceAsync<Parent>();

        if (auth.CurrentUser.Uid == users.ToString())
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "you are a parent", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else { Toast.MakeText(this, "you are a babysitter", ToastLength.Short).Show(); }
```

right now comparing the 2 is returning false i would like to match the current users ID to that of the one stored in users, any help or links would be great thanks.

Comment: Do not use images for code/errors/etc... Add the formatted code directly to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to match `Parent.id`, you can use `Any` (from `System.Linq`) on your List to do the comparison and at the first match it returns true:

```
if (users.Any((_) => _.id == auth.CurrentUser.Uid))
{
   // You are parent
}
```

Comment: Thanks SushiHangover.

Comment: @Jim Happy coding 